# SQLite locking specific columns

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to lock specific columns in a table, in order to prevent from a mistakely UPDATE command to modify those fields. On the contrary, some other columns should be allowed to be modified. Is there any specific SQL command for doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) to prevent this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PreventUpdateOfThisThat
BEFORE UPDATE OF ThisColumn, ThatColumn OF MyTable
BEGIN
  SELECT RAISE(FAIL, "don't do that!");
END;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. It was helpful.